# Update Parent record in hierarchical relationship

Tags: lookup, hierarchy

I want to be able to update parent record based on changes that I make in child record. Object A has 2 record types ABC and XYZ. And object A has self lookup. ABC is parent and XYZ is child record. When there is any changes in XYZ I want a status field to be updated in ABC record.

Since it is self lookup I can't use workflow field update or process flow as lond as I am aware. Can anyone please suggest if that is possible to use one of those ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can update the parent with a child update. I actually built this out as a test to confirm that it does work. You just need to make sure your criteria are correct. This even works recursively if the records are in a hierarchy.

---

[image: Process Builder Updating Parent]

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox. In Action when It asked for which record to update did you select related record record or record that has started the process? I am selecting related record and still can't get it to work.

Comment: @Ricky Check your filter criteria. It definitely works as advertised.

Comment: Yes SFDCFOX you are right. I was selecting incorrect filter criteria. Thanks for indicating that.That solved my issue.